# Using a file which is located within the iPhone sandbox

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, sandbox

I'm creating an iPhone app that needs the location of .wav which is located in the sandbox. I do this with the following:

```
 recordFilePath = (CFStringRef)[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"recordedFile.wav"];
```

How can I convert recordFilePath to a string that can then be passed into a C function?

---

**EDIT 1**

By the way, this is the statement that is going to receive the c string:

```
freopen ("locationOfFile/recordedFile.wav","r",stdin);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will depend on what type your c function expects to get - you can write a c function that accepts NSString* object as parameter. If you want to convert your `NSString` to `char*` then you can use one of the following functions:

```
– cStringUsingEncoding:
– getCString:maxLength:encoding:
– UTF8String
```

Comment: I like the idea of passing an NSString. Is that complicated? If so, maybe just passing a c string would be good. See Edit 1 which I'm about to post.

Comment: I think in your case you really need to convert NSString to char* - I'd use -UTF8String method for that